# Shiny: stop word splitting in VerbatimTextOutput

Tags: r, textbox, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny app with some text boxes. I like that the verbatimTextOutput has a box around the text, but with slightly longer text, the words get broken in meaningless places in order to wrap the text.
Is there some way that I can stop the words from being split? A very simple example is below.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(3, offset=0, verbatimTextOutput("TxtOut")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$TxtOut <- renderText(
    "a longish text that goes over multiple lines and breaks words"
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The `column` width is breaking your text. It is set to `3`; and the text wraps itself on that boundary.

Comment: If you still need to keep the same width, following will add a scroll and stop the text wrap. `tags$head(tags$style("#TxtOut {white-space: nowrap;}")),
      fluidRow(column(3, offset=0, verbatimTextOutput("TxtOut")))`

Comment: @ Sagar, great, thanks, that does the trick. I needed to keep the column width small because of other things that are on the page. If you submit it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad this helped. Posted as answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `column` width is set to `3`, your text is wrapping in the output function. As explained in the comments above, following `style` will prevent wrapping, and add a scroll bar to navigate.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style("#TxtOut {white-space: nowrap;}")),
  fluidRow(column(3, offset=0, verbatimTextOutput("TxtOut")))
)
```