# Printing data.tree in Shiny app without wrapping

Tags: r, shiny

When I try to print a data.tree object in a Shiny app, the text wraps around. This causes the tree to be distorted. I have recreated this below with the GNI2014 data and printing some of the columns again.

Server Code:

```
   output$text <- renderPrint({
     print(tree,"population", "GNI", "iso3", "pathString","continent")
   })
```

UI Code:

```
    verbatimTextOutput("text")
```

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u905H.png)

Is there a way to print the tree without wrapping the text?

I just found that it is fine in chrome but the text wraps in Safari

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shiny: stop word splitting in VerbatimTextOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914954/shiny-stop-word-splitting-in-verbatimtextoutput)